# Resizing Images using Pillow Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Right now I'm trying to resize a few .jpg files and my script is as following:

```
from PIL import Image

def main( ): #{

    filename = "amonstercallsmoviestill.jpg"

    image = Image.open(filename)
    size = width, height = image.size

    image.thumbnail((1600,900))

    image.show()

    del image
#}

if (__name__ == "__main__" ): #{

    main()
#}
```

I am trying to resize amonstercallsmoviestill.jpg to (1600,900) but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried with (300,300) and they work but whenever attempting thumbnail with (1600,900) it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: can you elaborate on "doesn't work" do you get an error? is it the wrong size? what happens...

Comment: No error shows up. Script runs and image.show() also works. Image just doesn't seem to be resized.

Comment: How big is the image to start with? I suspect that `thumbnail` can't be used to enlarge an image. The documentation says "Modifies the image to contain a thumbnail version of itself, no larger than the given size", which means that the resulting image could be much, much smaller than the size you give it. Have you tried using `resize` instead?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure on the size of it but I know for sure it's smaller than (1600,900) which could be the problem then. And yes, I did! Unfortunately using resized and thumbnail the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`thumbnail` only *reduces* the size of an image. To make it bigger, use `resize` instead.

```
image = image.resize((1600, 900), PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mark! LANCZOS is basically Antialias right ? I'm getting the following error running this - 'NameError: global name 'PIL' is not defined'.

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard it all depends on how you imported `PIL`, I was going straight from the documentation page. Try `Image.LANCZOS` instead. I was very disgusted with what I saw in the original PIL code for `ANTIALIAS`, I hope that when they forked it they introduced `LANCZOS` as a fix.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. This part of code worked but it still hasn't resized my image. :/

Comment: @TheOlDirtyBastard did you notice that `resize` doesn't work in place like `thumbnail` does? You need to assign the output like I did in my example.

Comment: Thank you! I've just tried it now and worked perfectly. Thank you thank you thank you! :D